# beamer: much more useable space in the frames

Tags: beamer

I would like to have something like a maximum of space wich I can use in my frames; with other words: 
· a minmum of "whitespace" in which is nothing 
· a very small "inner sep" 
· (what could I do else?)

So: How can I reduce empty spaces? 
And:
How can I realize that **all** is top-aligned?

[image]

```
\documentclass[t,% globally top alignment?
shadow=false, 
]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}

\author{}
\date{}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow!35}
% No shadows: 
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]



\begin{document}
\title{This is not really top-aligned... :(}
%\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.14]{logo-SF}}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Can I reduce the space above and below for that title? :(}
\titlepage
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{block1 is not top aligned :(}
          \begin{minipage}[c][0.16\textheight][c]{\linewidth} 
            text
          \end{minipage}
        \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{block2  is not top aligned :(}
            \[
                \begin{bmatrix}
                    f_{1} & f_{2} & f_{3}\\
                    s_{1} & 0 & 0 \\ 
                    0 & s_{2} & 0 
                \end{bmatrix}
            \]
        \end{block}
    \end{column}    
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need this setting for all slides of the presentation or just one?

Comment: Yes, for all frames.

Comment: Are you using `\section` and `\subsection`?  The point of that area at the top of `CambridgeUS` is to show the current section and subsection.  If you're using those, then how should that top area get reduced.  If you're not using those, then why are you using CambridgeUS?

Comment: Good question. Yes, do use (sub)sections. But, you are right, I consider to use `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title page of the presentation must have its own frame with subtitle, author, institute, etc.

To change the space above and below the title, it is possible to add some negative space, creating a new definition of the entire title page.

The first slide is displayed like this with an incomplete title page (missing author, institute and other elements from the definition)

Much better is to insert a title over the two blocks, configuring the font, color and spaces (second frame).

The blocks will be aligned on top using `\begin{columns}[T]`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[t,% globally top alignment?
shadow=false, 
]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}

\author{}
\date{}
\institute{}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow!35}
% No shadows: 
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]

\setbeamercolor{title in titlepage}{fg=red}
\setbeamerfont{title in titlepage}{size=\Large, series=\normalfont}
\def\titlepage{% new (incomplete) title page <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \centering%
    \vspace*{-1ex}% <<<<<<<<<<<<
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{title in titlepage}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in titlepage} \inserttitle}%
    \vspace*{-1ex}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,,
}

\begin{document}
    \title{This is not really top-aligned... :(}
    %\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.14]{logo-SF}}
    
    \begin{frame}{Can I reduce the space above and below for that title? :(}    
        \titlepage
        \begin{columns}[T]% use T <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
                \begin{block}{block1 is  top aligned :)}
                    \begin{minipage}[c][0.16\textheight][c]{\linewidth} 
                        text
                    \end{minipage}
                \end{block}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
                \begin{block}{block2  is  top aligned :)}
                    \[
                    \begin{bmatrix}
                        f_{1} & f_{2} & f_{3}\\
                        s_{1} & 0 & 0 \\ 
                        0 & s_{2} & 0 
                    \end{bmatrix}
                    \]
                \end{block}
            \end{column}    
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Can I reduce the space above and below for that title? :(}
        \vspace*{-1ex}% <<<<<<<<<<<<
        \centering  {\Large \textcolor{red}{This is not really top-aligned... :(}}
        \vspace*{-1ex}% <<<<<<<<<<<<
    %           \titlepage
    \begin{columns}[T]% use T <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{block1 is  top aligned :)}
                \begin{minipage}[c][0.16\textheight][c]{\linewidth} 
                    text
                \end{minipage}
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{block2  is  top aligned :)}
                \[
                \begin{bmatrix}
                    f_{1} & f_{2} & f_{3}\\
                    s_{1} & 0 & 0 \\ 
                    0 & s_{2} & 0 
                \end{bmatrix}
                \]
            \end{block}
        \end{column}    
    \end{columns}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, that helps me good. TYVM.